# custom maven plugin fail: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3379 at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, maven-plugin

I have written a custom maven plugin by java-annotations, and when run "mvn clean install" by jdk8 and maven 3.5.0, then get follow error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.5:descriptor (default-descriptor) on project pg-maven-plugin: Execution default-descriptor of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.5:descriptor failed: 3379 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.5:descriptor (default-descriptor) on project pg-maven-plugin: Execution default-descriptor of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.5:descriptor failed: 3379
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-descriptor of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.5:descriptor failed: 3379
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3379
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.extractor.annotations.scanner.DefaultMojoAnnotationsScanner.analyzeClassStream(DefaultMojoAnnotationsScanner.java:214)
        at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.extractor.annotations.scanner.DefaultMojoAnnotationsScanner.scanArchive(DefaultMojoAnnotationsScanner.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.extractor.annotations.scanner.DefaultMojoAnnotationsScanner.scan(DefaultMojoAnnotationsScanner.java:112)
        at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.extractor.annotations.scanner.DefaultMojoAnnotationsScanner.scan(DefaultMojoAnnotationsScanner.java:79)
        at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.extractor.annotations.JavaAnnotationsMojoDescriptorExtractor.scanAnnotations(JavaAnnotationsMojoDescriptorExtractor.java:124)
        at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.extractor.annotations.JavaAnnotationsMojoDescriptorExtractor.execute(JavaAnnotationsMojoDescriptorExtractor.java:103)
        at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.scanner.DefaultMojoScanner.populatePluginDescriptor(DefaultMojoScanner.java:96)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.plugin.AbstractGeneratorMojo.execute(AbstractGeneratorMojo.java:283)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.plugin.DescriptorGeneratorMojo.execute(DescriptorGeneratorMojo.java:90)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        ... 21 more
[ERROR]
```

Follow codes is pom:
    
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        4.0.0
        
            net.engining.pg
            pg-parent
            3.0.0-SNAPSHOT
            ..

```
    <name>PowerGear - 代码生成Maven插件</name>
    <artifactId>pg-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven-core.version>3.5.0</maven-core.version>
        <plexus-build-api.version>0.0.7</plexus-build-api.version>
        <maven-plugin-annotations.version>3.5</maven-plugin-annotations.version>
        <maven-plugin-plugin.version>3.5</maven-plugin-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.engining.pg</groupId>
            <artifactId>pg-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.engining.pg</groupId>
            <artifactId>pg-gwt</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-build-api</artifactId>
            <version>${plexus-build-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-plugin-annotations.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- 用里面的Java代码生成模型 -->
            <groupId>org.apache.ibatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>ibator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <description>用于生成基于PowerGear的基础数据库包装框架。用于代码生成的代码模型API基于ibator的内部工具类，其License基于Apache License V2，见 http://http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/tools/ibator/license.html </description>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-plugin-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-descriptor</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.apache.maven.plugins
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            maven-plugin-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [3.3,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>descriptor</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>obfuscated</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
                        <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.8</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>proguard</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <proguardVersion>5.2.1</proguardVersion>
                            <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
                            <addMavenDescriptor>true</addMavenDescriptor>
                            <options>
                                <option>-dontshrink</option>
                                <option>-dontoptimize</option>
                                <option>-keepattributes *Annotation*</option>
                                <option>-keepattributes Signature</option>
                                <option>-repackageclasses ''</option>
                                <option>-allowaccessmodification</option>
                                <option>-keepclasseswithmembers class * extends
                                    org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo { * ;}</option>
                                <option>-keepclasseswithmembers class
                                    net.engining.pg.maven.plugin.ui.Generation { * ;}</option>
                            </options>
                            <libs>
                                <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
                            </libs>
                        </configuration>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                                <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
                                <version>5.2.1</version>
                                <scope>runtime</scope>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: This is the root cause. `Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3379
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
   `

Comment: i know this, but why? i think it maybe come conflicts with asm, but how to find it?

Answer (score 13):

This error occurs when Maven scans your classpath for Mojo annotations. 
You need to tell the plugin where to look for annotations so that it will not scan the entire classpath. Here, I restrict scanning to the current project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>c.c.h</groupId>
  <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
  <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <mojoDependencies>
            <param>c.c.h:plugin</param>
          </mojoDependencies>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    ...
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: The mojoDependencies thing did not work for me. But upgrading from 3.2 to 3.4 did work.

Comment: Nice that savend my day in combination with <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>.

Answer (score 6):

I just ran into the same issue, but the faulty dependency was one of my own projects (which I really needed). Looking at the stack trace and the source it seems to happen while scanning a class for annotations, but the errors aren't particularly helpful.

I updated my maven-plugin-plugin from 3.2 to 3.5.1 and the problem went away. Here is my configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <goalPrefix>distribute</goalPrefix>
        <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>mojo-descriptor</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>descriptor</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>help-goal</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>helpmojo</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 5):

The answer of @end-user let me into the right direction. I could fix the issue by manually upgrading the version of the maven-plugin-plugin.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.2</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Haha, I basically came to the same solution as @sirolf2009, looked over it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It disappeared when I removed one of the depencencies, in my case it was

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.0.201706111038-r</version>
    </dependency>
```

It seems that maven-plugin is ill-behaving in combination with certain other dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, when I noticed this:

```
[INFO] Mojo extractor for language: java found 9 mojo descriptors.
[INFO] Applying mojo extractor for language: bsh
[INFO] Mojo extractor for language: bsh found 0 mojo descriptors.
[INFO] Applying mojo extractor for language: java-annotations
```

I was able to resolve it by limiting the extractors:

```
<configuration>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <extractors>
        <extractor>java</extractor>
    </extractors>
</configuration>
```

I believe it was the last one, the `java-annotations` extractor, that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try different versions. For me 3.6 did not work, but 3.5 did. In short, try all versions higher than the one you have. 3.4, 3.5, 3.6..etc

Comment: `3.6.4` worked for me with *Java 1.8* (also `maven.compiler.source` and `maven.compiler.target`), `maven-plugin-annotations:3.4`, `maven-plugin-api:3.0`

Answer (score 0):

thanks for @mblaszczyk mention, your solution give me hint， and i debuged and finally find the conflict dependencies, it's "aspectjtools", get rid off the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inexplicably, I found that this was the guilty dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-migrationsupport</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```