# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on build project

Tags: android, kotlin, indexoutofboundsexception

**When i trying to build project on linux im getting this error on build:**

[image]

**The log :**

[image]

On windows there is no such error on build

Comment: I'll recommend you to clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: Don't add screenshots of code or errors - paste it directly into the question

Comment: I am agree with @SharanSalian in addition you need to perform `Invalidate Cache/Restart` from `file` menu.

Comment: Do you use arraylist in your project?please share your code

Comment: @Zoe you have not added your favorite comment here..... 

Comment: @VikaS what do you mean?

Comment: Ok, I need to frank now, I always (almost) see @Zoe favourite message: `Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should only be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it.`. I think that @VikaS meant. @Zoe, you're stole my times and happiness by making me always hoping that you're in the question comment :P :P

Answer (score 0):

Found the [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312695/custom-maven-plugin-fail-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-3379-at-org).
I just had to delete old\broken dependencies.

@Zoe sry :) First time posting question here.